# How do I fill in the input type= "time" field in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The Spring-Boot + Thymeleaf project does not fill in the input type= "time" field When opening the html form.
That's how it works:

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputTime" th:value=${CarEntity.timeOperation} required>
```

And here it is:

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputTime" th:field="*{timeOperation}" required>
```

Or so:

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputTime" th:field="*{timeOperation}" th:value=${CarEntity.timeOperation} required>
```

The field remains empty.
And if I use <input type= " text> then everything works fine.

```html
<form id="f-pr-03" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/edit/{id}(id=${carEntity.getId()})}" th:object="${carEntity}">
That's how everything works and displays and reads.
    <label for="inputName">Input name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" th:field="*{name}" required>

But this is not displayed
    <label for="inputPTTime">Input time</label>
    <input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputPTTime" th:field="*{timeOperation}" max="17:50" min="00:01" required>

And this is how it is displayed, but not transmitted by the POST method 
    <label for="inputPTTime">Input time</label>
    <input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputPTTime" th:value=${CarEntity.timeOperation} max="17:50" min="00:01" required>
    <button type="submit" name="action">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Just for clarification: Your first example using `th:value=${CarEntity.timeOperation}` should work correctly, as long as `timeOperation` returns a string such as `13:30`. See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Value). Does your first example work correctly?

Comment: Or, if you also want to display seconds, the string can be something like: `13:30:45`. (Again, just for clarification.)

Comment: The first example works correctly. but i need the value not only to be read from the variable, but also to be written to the timeoperation variable.

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` with a `th:object` attribute around that input?

Comment: The first option only records the time in the Input field. but when i do the post method, nothing is read from this field (null). And in the second version, it is read from it, but not written. How do I make both reading and writing work?

Comment: Yes, I added the code with the form

Answer (score 0):

I don't if it is still relevant since it's benn a while. Thymeleaf provides a special attribute th:field responsible for binding input fields with a property in the bean class. This attribute behaves differently depending on whether it is attached to. Thymeleaf supports all-new input types introduced in HTML5 such as type="color" or type="datetime".

Please check this out for more info:

https://frontbackend.com/thymeleaf/working-with-forms-in-thymeleaf